# Getting a ratio of the values of a pivoted dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

One of my dataframes contains

```
WR          # WR
SP-RS-001    191
SP-RS-004    120
CO-CL-003    130
AN-AS-003    127
```

and the other contains

```
C ID      SP-RS-001    SP-RS-004  CO-CL-003   AN-AS-003 ....
C-001        4            15         19         18      ....
C-002        7            11         10          0      ....
C-004        0             5          7         12      ....
C-005        1             1          4          2      ....
```

How can I make another dataframe that gives me a ratio/percentage of the value from the second dataframe to the value of the first dataframe's row corresponding to it. So, the result should look like -

```
C ID      SP-RS-001      SP-RS-004    CO-CL-003    AN-AS-003      ....
C-001        4/191         15/120      19/130         18/127      ....
C-002        7/191         11/120      10/130          0/127      ....
C-004        0/191          5/120       7/130         12/127      ....
C-005        1/191          1/120       4/130          2/127      ....
```

I mean the actual percentage value after dividing the values above. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try doing:

```
help_df=pd.concat([df.set_index('WR').T]*len(df1)).reset_index(drop=True)
df1.iloc[:,1:]=df1.iloc[:,1:].div(help_df)
print(df1)

    C ID  SP-RS-001  SP-RS-004  CO-CL-003  AN-AS-003
0  C-001  0.020942   0.125000   0.146154   0.141732 
1  C-002  0.036649   0.091667   0.076923   0.000000 
2  C-004  0.000000   0.041667   0.053846   0.094488 
3  C-005  0.005236   0.008333   0.030769   0.015748
```

Where `print(help_df)` is basically a helper df for division:

```
   WR  SP-RS-001  SP-RS-004  CO-CL-003  AN-AS-003
    0   191        120        130        127      
    1   191        120        130        127      
    2   191        120        130        127      
    3   191        120        130        127
```

Comment: Why `len(df1)`?

Comment: @harry04 basically concating and the helper df to make same length of `df1` before division

Comment: It gives me a lot more rows than expected.

Comment: @harry04 make sure that the number of columns and rows in helper df is same as the columns you want to divide(like the example)

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(text):
    l = []
    for i in text.index:
        #print(i)
        temp = df1[df1['WR'] == i].reset_index()
        if len(temp) >= 1:
            #print(temp['#WR'][0])
            l.append(str(text[i])+'/'+str(temp['#WR'][0]))
    return l 

df2[['SP-RS-001', 'SP-RS-004', 'CO-CL-003', 'AN-AS-003']] = df2.apply(check, axis=1)

main = df2[['SP-RS-001', 'SP-RS-004', 'CO-CL-003', 'AN-AS-003']].T.reset_index()
main.columns=['CID', 'SP-RS-001', 'SP-RS-004', 'CO-CL-003', 'AN-AS-003']
```

**Output**

```
         CID SP-RS-001 SP-RS-004 CO-CL-003 AN-AS-003
0  SP-RS-001     4/191    15/120    19/130    18/127
1  SP-RS-004     7/191    11/120    10/130     0/127
2  CO-CL-003     0/191     5/120     7/130    12/127
3  AN-AS-003     1/191     1/120     4/130     2/127
```

Comment: Sorry but your output doesn't match my requirements. Why does `CID` list the `WR`s in the above output...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the WR as index for the first dataframe , w.r.t to the column name of a 2nd dataframe you can fetch the value using `df.loc`

```
df.set_index('WR',inplace=True)

            #WR.1
WR  
SP-RS-001   191
SP-RS-004   120
CO-CL-003   130
AN-AS-003   127


df1
    C ID    SP-RS-001   SP-RS-004   CO-CL-003   AN-AS-003
0   C-001   4   15  19  18
1   C-002   7   11  10  0
2   C-004   0   5   7   12
3   C-005   1   1   4   2

df1.apply(lambda x: x/int(df.loc[x.name]) if x.name in df.index else x)


Out:

     C ID   SP-RS-001   SP-RS-004   CO-CL-003   AN-AS-003
0   C-001   0.020942    0.125000    0.146154    0.141732
1   C-002   0.036649    0.091667    0.076923    0.000000
2   C-004   0.000000    0.041667    0.053846    0.094488
3   C-005   0.005236    0.008333    0.030769    0.015748
```

Comment: Do I have to set the `C ID` as `index` for the 2nd dataframe as well?

Comment: Not needed, the condition in apply function don't take other columns

Comment: I'm getting a `NameError: ("name 'name' is not defined", occurred at index SP-RS-001')`

Comment: It's the same as what I've written above!